# Swift Multithreading Getter

Tags: swift, multithreading, getter

I have a function `getAccessToken()` that makes an API call and may return on a separate thread but I need my program to wait until it returns to continue.

I know I can use `dispatch` to make sure it returns on the same thread but I am curious if a variable with a getter making the call would accomplish the same thing.

ex:

```
var accesstoken : String {
    get {
         return getAccessToken()
    }
}
```

The reason I ask is because when I access the token I want to be able to just use one line of code instead of having to make sure to wait for the token to return every time.

Ideally I would be able to do something like `Common.getAccessToken()` or `Common.accessToken` and not have to do anything extra.

Comment: I would expect it to return whatever `getAccessToken()` returns and with the same timing.

Comment: `accesstoken` doesn't achieve anything that `getAccessToken()` doesn't. It just adds a layer of indirection. Why do you not want to use `DIspatch`?

Comment: @Alexander the program has about 4 people currently working on it and simplifying the process for getting a token will reduce the amount of time they spend on it and the number of errors and I don't want to rely on them remembering to put `dispatch` around each time they want the token.

Comment: @PhillipMills Ok, so if I used `accesstoken` I could still run into the issue where `getAccessToken()` hasn't returned by the time I want to use it?

Comment: @dpb That's why you put the disptach call inside a computed property.

Comment: @dpb Wait, what do you mean "may return on a separate thread". Functions can't "return on a seperate thread" (with the exception of things like `fork`). Do you mean to say that it invokes a completion handler on a seperate thread? How exactly does `getAccessToken()` work?

Comment: I'll basically echo @Alexander here.  Without knowing how `getAccessToken()` works, there's nothing I can tell you about what it will return or when.

Comment: @Alexander `getAccessToken()` utilizes Alamofire and does use a completion handler.

Comment: @dpb That's the kind of thing you need to include in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example doesn't achieve anything that a direct call `getAccessToken()` couldn't do. What you need is to wrap that call in a synchronous dispatch call:

```
class MyType {
    let queue: DispatchQueue

    //...

    private func generateAccessToken() -> String {
        //...
    }

    public var accessToken: String {
        return queue.sync { generateAccessToken() }
    }
}
```